# How to integrate Qt Mobility 1.1.0 to Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-mobility

could any body provide me steps (with screen shots) of integrating Qt Mobility 1.1.0 with Qt Creator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the [installation guide from Nokia here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.1-tp/installation.html)

and then add some lines to your .pro file, and a macro to your cpp file [as detailed here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.1.0/quickstart.html), you'll be able to include QObjects from qtmobility APIs, get code completion etc in QtCreator etc.

Comment: I followed these instructions, with the `configure` command line completing successfully, but Qt Creator still uses the 1.0.2 headers (which it shipped with). Any thoughts?